# MonoTouch universal iPhone/iPad app & code duplication

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

The MonoDevelop IDE, for MonoTouch app, creates separate classes and AppDelegates for iPhone/iPad and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to inherit them from the same base class.
Having separate AppDelegate classes would likely result in code duplication in the application.

Can anyone suggest a better app structure for the universal iPhone/iPad app than the one produced by the MonoDevelop IDE?

Alternatively, can anyone suggest any way to have the code common to both AppDelegates not be duplicated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've looked several times, and never found, a good example (with source) of a universal app in MonoTouch.  Would really love to find one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use MonoTouch (I like the features Objective-C provides a lot) myself, but [according to their docs](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/API_Design) it supports normal object inheritance. So just create your own AppDelegate with the commonly reused methods in it which inherits from `MonoTouch.UIApplicationDelegate`. Then modify the AppDelegates generated by the Universal application template to inherit from your custom AppDelegate, and remove any methods in those which your base class implements.